# If I stop fermentation early does the sugar left in juice still turns into Co2 after bottling

Tags: fermentation, priming, sweetness

I am trying to understand a little bit about science process between Fermentation (when sugar is turned into alcohol) and Priming (when fermentable sugar is turned into).
I have done several batches of cider now and notice that every time fermentation transforms all sugar in juice into alcohol making it Very dry. Therefor i was thinking of stopping fermentation process early when there is still some 20% of natural sugars left in juice, but the question is: If I stop the fermentation and there is still 20% of sugar will the sugar left not just be turned into Co2 in priming process and thus make the drink more carbonated but still fully dry?
I guess the bottom line is- is there a way to preserve natural sweetness and not turning it into alcohol in fermentation or Co2 in priming process?

Answer (score 6):

Priming is really just another word for fermentation, sometimes called secondary fermentation.

If you stop fermentation when 20% of sugar remains, you normally do this by killing the yeast. This means it will not ferment further in the bottle.

On the other hand if you bottle it with 20% of the sugar left and some active yeast, you'll generally find fermentation continues. This typically leads to your bottles exploding! It is actually somewhat tricky to get a carbonated, but not fully fermented, product in basic homebrewing. You might try different yeasts but at least in my experience, this only slows things down. If sugar remains, it *will* eventually get fermented unless you pasteurise or ensure the temperature is kept low enough.

This is one reason that commercially, drinks are force-carbonated. They kill the yeast and stabilise the drink, then artificially carbonate it in the bottle using CO2.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Boy, This is very helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by: "keep the drink very carefully chilled"

Comment: @Philippe I mean that if you cannot maintain a consistent low temperature, it _will_ start fermenting and this can be dangerous. It needs to stay in a temperature controlled environment really.